# php How to show original searched query on html page using while using htmlentities

Tags: php, html, xss, html-entities

I am using htmlentities while echoing the searched query on html page to prevent XSS attacks (thats what i read),

i am showing it on 2 places, like this

```
<?echo htmlentities($_GET['q']);?>
```

but this is converting some characters to their html equivalent like

```
< becomes &lt;
> becomes &gt;
```

how can show the original entered value , and prevent the xss attacks too.

i have seen some sites showing the exact entered value by user. how are they doing it ?

update:

i am displaying the search query to the user.
i am taking search query using get paramater and while showing it , i am using htmlentities.

but in the normal browser it `showing &lt; instead of <`

*`while in other sites it shows exactly < in normal browser and in source it shows &lt;`*

**Update :**

using

```
$searchq = htmlentities($q, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8', false);
```

solved the issue, need to check where is the double htmlentities are being applied,.

Comment: Are you viewing that in a browser? The whole point of using HTML entities is that it performs those replacements- that is what HTML entities **are**. In the browser, those entities (e.g. `&lt;`) should appear as their corresponding characters (e.g. `<`). If you look at the source code for those sites, you'll see they're using HTML entities as well.

Comment: yes i am viewing in the browser, so how are they doing it exactly.? its looks normal in browser while in source it shows html equivalent values.

Comment: Right- it's not actually something they're doing. The browser does it for them. It sees those HTML entities and knows to transform them into their corresponding characters when it displays them to the end user. When you use them in your own web page, and open that page up in your browser, do you see the HTML version, or the version you want to see? You shouldn't need to do anything special.

Comment: i am seeing the html version, while i want to see < >

Comment: Hmm... Do you have a doctype declaration at the top of your HTML file? What are the headers your server is sending with the file? Is the file extension .htm or .html, or is it .txt? Your browser will only interpret HTML entities if it knows the file it's seeing is HTML; if it thinks the file is plaintext, it will just show the raw file.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> and its php file seein it as html

Comment: When you use "view source" on your page, what do you see? My guess is it will look like `&amp;gt;`, indicating that it has been escaped (htmlentities/htmlspecialchars) *twice*. (`&amp;` is the escaped form of `&`). In that case, you need to track down where that's happening, so you only escape it once, immediately before displaying.

Comment: source shows &amp;lt; , is it because of using urldecode before and then using htmlentities?

Answer (score 0):

What you put in your query doesn't have to be the same as what you display on the web page, right? 
You can save the original `$_GET` in a session for example and for displaying it on the webpage you use `htmlentities($_SESSION['search_query'])` i.e.

If you would reload the query all the time and use `htmlentities($_GET);` then you can expect after the second load something like `htmlentities(htmlentities($_GET));` and that will show strange output.

Furthermore htmlentities is used for exactly the purpose of converting the characters to html entities.
I would recommend using mysqli_real_escape_string or even better prepared statements.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: He didn't mention databases. Although you're right, he should use prepared statements to enter things into the database, and then HTML-escape database output before putting it into the webpage.

Comment: nope, what i want is entered string to be displayed as it is without causing xss vulnerability., i am using htmlentities and its converting to the &lt;

Comment: Then why don't you just echo it without the function?

Comment: because i read it will allow xss attackers to include malicious code in my website. either this or i read wrong.

Comment: So the query is more than 'just' a search query? Do you display the queries also to other users? IMO if you convert it to html entities and it is displayed good in the browser, why bother that the & becomes a &amp;? This is expected behavior and complies with the w3c standard. Correct me if I am wrong.